# JQL Distinct with Entities having @Lob attributes

Tags: jpa, jpql

In a JPA application with EclipseLink, there is a Circular entity has oneToMany relationship with Keyword entity. Circular entity has two attributes of @Lob type. When I run this JQL to get distinct entities, I get the following error. How can I use distinct in with such entities with @Lob attributes?

JQL is

```
SQL is select DISTINCT c from CircularKeyword k join k.circular c where c.retired = false and c.administrativeDivision.id = 1  and k.retired = false and  ( upper(c.circularNumber) like '%3%' or  upper(c.topic) like '%3%' or  upper(k.name) like '%3%'   )  order by c.name
```

Error is

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Columns of type 'BLOB' may not be used in CREATE INDEX, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT or DISTINCT statements because comparisons are not supported for that type.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT DISTINCT t0.ID, t0.BAIMAGE, t0.CIRCULARDATE, t0.CIRCULARLANGUAGE, t0.CIRCULARNUMBER, t0.CODE, t0.CONTENTS, t0.CREATEDAT, t0.DESCRIPTION, t0.FILENAME, t0.FILETYPE, t0.INTERNAL, t0.KEYWORDS, t0.NAME, t0.ORIGINATINGFILENO, t0.RETIRECOMMENTS, t0.RETIRED, t0.RETIREDAT, t0.TOPIC, t0.ADMINISTRATIVEDIVISION_ID, t0.CATEGORY_ID, t0.CREATER_ID, t0.PERSON_ID, t0.RETIRER_ID, t0.SIGNINGAUTHORITY_ID FROM CIRCULAR t0, CIRCULARKEYWORD t1 WHERE (((((t0.RETIRED = ?) AND (t0.ADMINISTRATIVEDIVISION_ID = ?)) AND (t1.RETIRED = ?)) AND ((UCASE(t0.CIRCULARNUMBER) LIKE ? OR UCASE(t0.TOPIC) LIKE ?) OR UCASE(t1.NAME) LIKE ?)) AND (t0.ID = t1.CIRCULAR_ID)) ORDER BY t0.NAME ASC
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=CircularKeyword sql="SELECT DISTINCT t0.ID, t0.BAIMAGE, t0.CIRCULARDATE, t0.CIRCULARLANGUAGE, t0.CIRCULARNUMBER, t0.CODE, t0.CONTENTS, t0.CREATEDAT, t0.DESCRIPTION, t0.FILENAME, t0.FILETYPE, t0.INTERNAL, t0.KEYWORDS, t0.NAME, t0.ORIGINATINGFILENO, t0.RETIRECOMMENTS, t0.RETIRED, t0.RETIREDAT, t0.TOPIC, t0.ADMINISTRATIVEDIVISION_ID, t0.CATEGORY_ID, t0.CREATER_ID, t0.PERSON_ID, t0.RETIRER_ID, t0.SIGNINGAUTHORITY_ID FROM CIRCULAR t0, CIRCULARKEYWORD t1 WHERE (((((t0.RETIRED = ?) AND (t0.ADMINISTRATIVEDIVISION_ID = ?)) AND (t1.RETIRED = ?)) AND ((UCASE(t0.CIRCULARNUMBER) LIKE ? OR UCASE(t0.TOPIC) LIKE ?) OR UCASE(t1.NAME) LIKE ?)) AND (t0.ID = t1.CIRCULAR_ID)) ORDER BY t0.NAME ASC")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `circular` has a simple id, you could get around this by updating your query to select only the distinct *identifiers* as a subquery:

```
SELECT k.circular FROM CircularKeyword k 
WHERE k.circular.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.id FROM CircularKeyword k2 
                        JOIN k2.circular c ...rest of your query...)
```

The important thing is that you are asking for `DISTINCT c.id` instead of `DISTINCT c` so that the generated native SQL will not include your `BLOB` columns with the `DISTINCT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that you can do to work around this issue is wrapping your @Lob into a separate entity. This works because it will not try to resolve the actual lob but only the lob key reference which the database can handle with distinct. I have adapted a working code piece to an example with provided information.

Circular Entity

```
//Other attributes, and ids omitted

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "LOB_ATTRIBUTE_1_KEY")
LobAttribute lobAttribute1;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "LOB_ATTRIBUTE_2_KEY")
LobAttribute lobAttribute2;
```

LobAttribute Entity

```
@Id
@Column(name = "LOB_ATTRIBUTE_KEY")
Long lobAttributeKey;

@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "LOB")
String lob;
```

I don't particularly like this but I believe it is the best solution with the least restrictions on the queries and the model. I hope this helps anyone else who comes across this.